# Can't connect my 'BrowserFactory' to 'Selenium Grid'

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-grid

I can't connect my BrowserFactory to Selenium Grid. Any ideas why the following code won't work?

```
public static WebDriver getDriver() throws Exception {
  try {
    // Load the driver selected by user
    Properties p = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(Constant.CONFIG_PROPERTIES_DIRECTORY);
    p.load(fi);
    if(p.getProperty("use_grid").equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
      DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
      desiredCapabilities.getBrowserName();
      desiredCapabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
      return new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), desiredCapabilities);
    }
    String browserName = p.getProperty("browser");
    switch (browserName) {
      case "firefox":
        if (null == webdriver) {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", Constant.GECKO_DRIVER_DIRECTORY);
          webdriver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        break;
```

1. I have the node and grid up and running successfully.

Thanks.

Comment: `desiredCapabilities.getBrowserName();` looks like it's just asking what the browser name is... have you set the browser before that? You probably need a line like `desiredCapabilities.setBrowserName("firefox");`

Comment: A couple of other questions. What do you mean when you say your code won't work? Does that mean it runs locally instead? Or throws an error? If there is an error, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not setting the browser when using selenium grid. Try changing this line:

```
desiredCapabilities.getBrowserName();
```

to this:

```
desiredCapabilities.setBrowserName("firefox");
```

or this if you're properties are in the correct format and that code is working correctly:

```
desiredCapabilities.setBrowserName(p.getProperty("browser"));
```